# react-apollo refetch doesn't work unless notifyOnNetworkStatusChange is set to true?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

## working repo https://github.com/github0013/react-apollo-refetch

If you set `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange={false}` at this line,
https://github.com/github0013/react-apollo-refetch/blob/master/index.tsx#L25
, you will NOT see data in console.

> **notifyOnNetworkStatusChange**
>   https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo#graphql-config-options-notifyOnNetworkStatusChange
>
> Whether or not updates to the network status or network error should trigger re-rendering of your component.

Does this mean that if we want to use `refetch()`, we also have to set notifyOnNetworkStatusChange = true to get components updated automatically?
* unless otherwise we manually update changes by such as `refetch().then(data => updateMyComponent(data))`?